CSS `gap` property not working when `display: block;` is set
I'm encountering an issue where the gap property in CSS isn't having any effect on my layout. Upon inspection, I noticed that some of my containers have display: block; set, which seems to be preventing gap from working as expected. Specifically, I'm trying to use gap to create spacing between elements within a container.
Here's a simplified example of my CSS setup:
.centered-div {
  display: block; /* Problematic line */
  /* Other properties */
  gap: 24px; /* Doesn't work */
}

I understand that gap is primarily used with flex containers (display: flex; or display: inline-flex;). However, changing display: block; to display: flex; isn't feasible for this particular container due to layout constraints.
Is there a way to achieve spacing between elements (gap) without changing display: block; to display: flex;? Or is there an alternative approach that I can use to achieve similar spacing effects in a non-flex container?
Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

In flow layout, gaps are created by margins.

What do you mean?

Use margin on child elements

.centered-div {
  padding: 24px 0;
}

.centered-div > * {
  margin-bottom: 24px;
}

.centered-div > *:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

Using the above methods should help you achieve the desired spacing between elements without needing to switch to a flex or grid layout.
Here Is the Codepen Link you can watch the output to watch my suggestion so you can get better idea
